# Condition in range function in python

Tags: python

Is there any syntax in python to create `range` with condition ?
For example:

`in range(101, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)`

count all numbers, divisible by `11`. Iterating over all range like

`len([i for i in range(101, 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999) if % 11 = 0])` is very slow. I tried to do vectorization filtering on numpy array

`np.arange(101,  9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999, dtype=np.int8)`

but numpy throws

```
Maximum allowed size exceeded
```

So my guess is to initially do not include do not dividable numbers in range. Is there any way to do it in `range` function ?

Comment: Any number divisible by 11 would be just using `11` as the step: `range(0, 9999.., 11)`? No need to generate all numbers and then test them, just start at the first number divisible by 11 after your starting index and increase the value by 11 each time.

Comment: Even if the `step` argument would not suit your needs, you could just create a simple generator or generator expression that would.

Comment: @Axe319 the step argument is actually suitable, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any number that is divisible by 11 would be starting at the first number after your starting index that can be divided by 11 (which should be quick to find: `s_idx + 11 - s_idx % 11` should work), and then using the `step` parameter to `range` to move 11 each time.

```
range(start, end, 11)
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it O(n) ?

Comment: How is this not O(n)?

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, you could just do

```
def range_mod(start, stop, mod):
    return range(start + start % mod, stop, mod)

print(len(range_mod(101, 9999, 11)))
```

But here is a more general example for a range function that iterates with arbitrary condition:

```
def range_with_condition(start, stop, func):
    for i in range(start, stop):
        if func(i):
            yield i

                                                                                                                                                                 
def mycondition(i):
    return i % 11 == 0


for i in range_with_condition(101, 999, mycondition):
    print(i)
```

Edit: I've been suggested the simpler syntax

```
for i in filter(lambda i: i % 11 == 0, range(101, 999)):
     print(i)
```

Comment: `range_mod(10, 20, 11)` returns `0`.

Comment: `range_with_condition` could just use `filter`.

Comment: Is there any way to do it O(n) ?

Comment: This should in principle be O(n)...is it not?

Answer (score 0):

I came up without range

```
((y // k) - (x // k)) + 1 if x % k == 0 else (y // k) - (x // k)
```

Comment: How does this meet the OP's need for all numbers meeting a condition in a range?  I suggest that it does not.